# Android ROOM Dao class insert query unit test coverage is 75%. How to achieve 100% code coverage?

Tags: android, junit, code-coverage, android-room, android-instrumentation

[Dao insert query coverage][75%]

I have tried to cover unit test cases for Android Room DAO classes. The 'insert' query code coverage is only 75%. How to achieve 100%? Checking code coverage through Jacoco plugin.

I have CategoryDaoTest instrumentation test class that test all queries deals with "category" table.
I have CategoryDao class that includes all queries to table "category"
The test passes but the code coverage for insert shows 75%. The code coverage for getCategories() shows 100% in Jacoco plugin.

```
@Dao
interface CategoryDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM category")
    fun getCategories(): LiveData<List<Category>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(category: Category)
}
```

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class CategoryDaoTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var appDatabase: AppDatabase
    private lateinit var categoryDao: CategoryDao

    @Before
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun initDb() {
        appDatabase = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java
        ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        categoryDao = appDatabase.categoryDao()
    }

    @After
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun closeDb() {
        appDatabase.close()
    }

    @Test
    @Throws(InterruptedException::class)
    fun onFetchingCategory() {
        val categoryList = LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(categoryDao.getCategories())
        Assert.assertTrue(categoryList.isEmpty())
    }

    @Test
    @Throws(InterruptedException::class)
    fun onInsertingACategory() {
        val createdData = CategoryFactory.makeCategory()
        categoryDao.insert(createdData)

        val categoryList = LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(categoryDao.getCategories())
        Assert.assertTrue(categoryList.isNotEmpty())
        Assert.assertTrue(categoryList.size == 1)
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvW9q.png
```